# JSON to NSDictionary literal

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I need to build an `NSDictionary` that I can then parse with `NSJSONSerialization` in order to get a nice `JSON` formatted string.

The final output of my JSON needs to be something like:

```
"Viewport":{
        "BottomRight":{
            "Latitude":1.26743233E+15,
            "Longitude":1.26743233E+15
        },
        "TopLeft":{
            "Latitude":1.26743233E+15,
            "Longitude":1.26743233E+15
        }
    }
```

I figured it might be easiest to use `NSDictionary` literals, but how would I create multi-level nested dictionaries doing it this way?

Also, I will need to be setting the lat and long values when creating the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can arbitrarily nest liberals:

```
@{@"Viewport":@{
    @"BottomRight":@{
        @"Latitude":@(1267...),
        @"Longitude":@(126...)
    },
    ...
```